# PowerShell script to export to single CSV

Tags: powershell, csv, output

I need help to get the following PowerShell script to output too just one .CSV file instead of the current two. Can someone please help?  I'm wanting to get the SNMP settings that are set on remote servers. The information I'm after is held in the registry. $DellAdmKey is one key that holds SubKeys and refers to the "communityNames". Within each of the SubKeys I get the "Value Data" which refers to the "TrapDestinations". $DellAdmKey2 is a Key called "ValidCommunities" but does not have Subkeys, it just has DWORD values that refer to "AcceptedCommunityNames" and the "Rights". So the foreach on the 1st line can't be used as "ValidCommunities" does not contain SubKeys

```
$servers = "ServerName"
$BaseKey = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey(‘LocalMachine’, $server)
$SubKey= $BaseKey.OpenSubKey("SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Services\\SNMP\Parameters",$true)
$DellAdmKey = $BaseKey.OpenSubKey("SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Services\\SNMP\\Parameters\\TrapConfiguration\\",$true)
$DellAdmKey2 = $BaseKey.OpenSubKey("SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Services\\SNMP\\Parameters\\ValidCommunities\\",$true)

$DellAdmKey.GetSubKeyNames() | foreach {
$action = $_
$subkey = $DellAdmKey.openSubKey($_)
$subkey.GetValueNames() | foreach {$_ | Select 
@{name="ServerName";Expression={$server}},
@{Name="CommunityNames";Expression={$action}},
@{name="TrapDestinations";Expression={$subkey.getvalue($_)}}
    } | Export-Csv c:\temp\1.csv -NoTypeInformation  
}

$action = $_
$subkey = $DellAdmKey2.openSubKey($_)
$subkey.GetValueNames() | foreach {
$_ | Select @{name="ServerName";Expression={$server}},
@{name="AcceptedCommunityNames";Expression={$_}},
@{name="Rights";Expression={$subkey.getvalue($_)}}
    } | Export-Csv c:\temp\2.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: @madth3 - because putting words in back ticks makes it unreadable - also see discussion http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/201617/shouldnt-reviews-be-done-a-bit-more-carefully

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question (and your code) correctly, the third group of instructions is supposed to go inside the `$DellAdmKey.GetSubKeyNames() | foreach { ... }`. In that case you simply need to move the `| Export-Csv` outside that loop to capture all output in one CSV. You need to make sure all objects have the same set of properties, though.

```
$DellAdmKey.GetSubKeyNames() | foreach {
  $action = $_
  $subkey = $DellAdmKey.openSubKey($action)
  $subkey.GetValueNames() | Select @{name="ServerName";Expression={$server}},
      @{Name="CommunityNames";Expression={$action}},
      @{name="TrapDestinations";Expression={$subkey.getvalue($_)}}
      @{name="AcceptedCommunityNames";Expression={}},
      @{name="Rights";Expression={}}

  $subkey = $DellAdmKey2.openSubKey($action)
  $subkey.GetValueNames() | Select @{name="ServerName";Expression={$server}},
      @{Name="CommunityNames";Expression={}},
      @{name="TrapDestinations";Expression={}},
      @{name="AcceptedCommunityNames";Expression={$_}},
      @{name="Rights";Expression={$subkey.getvalue($_)}}
} | Export-Csv 'c:\temp\out.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

---

**Edit:** If you really just want to run the code as you posted (which seems somewhat dubious to me, since `$_` in line 17 should be empty), you could change the second `Export-Csv` instruction to

```
... | Export-Csv 'c:\temp\1.csv' -Append -NoTypeInformation
```

provided you're running PowerShell v3. Prior to that something like this should do:

```
... | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | select -Skip 1 |
  Out-File 'c:\temp\1.csv' -Append
```

Either way you should make sure all the objects you're exporting have the same set of properties, though. Otherwise you might end up with `Rights` values in the `TrapDestination` column or some such.

Comment: Thank you for responding, no that's the problem as the $DellAdmKey2 does not reside under a subKey like $DellAdmKey does. They are a "DWORD" of "ValidCommunities" to which I need the Value Name and Value Data. The scrip I posted outputs correctly to each CSV ok. But need to combine it but that's where i'm stuck.

Comment: Looks like my approach is wrong? Let me explain what i'm after and see if there is a better way. $DellAnmKey has SubKey's

Comment: Let me explain what i'm after and see if there is a better way. I'm wanting to get the SNMP settings that are set on remove servers. The information I'm after is held in the registry. $DellAdmKey is one key that holds SubKeys referred to as "communityNames" and within each SubKey I get the "Value Data" referred to "TrapDestination". $DellAdmKey2 is a Key called "ValidCommunities" but does not have Subkeys, it just has DWORD values referred to as "AcceptedCommunityNames" and "Rights". So the foreach on the 1st line can't be used as "ValidCommunities" does not contain SubKeys.

Comment: @user1890242 In that case replace the second `$subkey.GetValueNames()` with `$DellAdmKey2.GetValueNames()` and remove the 2 lines before it.

Comment: "No good" is an insufficient problem description. Update your question with the code you're currently using, a sample of the created output, and a sample of what that output is supposed to look like.

Answer (score 0):

I have resorted to using this  http://psrr.codeplex.com/ it make life easier. Thanks for the replies Ansgar.